# Emacs: cl-loop and repeatedly calculated values

Tags: loops, elisp, emacs24

Looping in lisp can be a bit bothersome, which is greatly alleviated by the `cl-loop` macro. However, I find myself repeatedly writing hackish things like

```
(cl-loop for item in some-list 
     with temp-var do (setf temp-var (some-function-of item))
     ...)

(cl-loop for item in some-list
     for x = (some-function-of item) then (some-function-of item)
     ...)
```

Is there some more elegant way of calculating some value every iteration *in the same way*? Note that it must be visible on the toplevel of `cl-loop` for otherwise it will not be available for doing conditional `collect` or `return` statements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you include the `then` clause?  I'm pretty sure

```
(cl-loop for item in some-list
         for x = (some-function-of item)
         ...)
```

should do.

Alternatively, you could calculate all new values up-front on loop initialization:

```
(loop for item     in some-list
      for mod-item in (mapcar 'some-function-of some-list)
      ...)
```

You may want to bind `some-list` as a variable using a `with` or `let` if it is a complex expression.

Comment: Hm, seems I must have done something wrong, then I tried leaving out the then clause before. Tried it again and yes, it behaves as you say. When I last tried it did not, for some reason. Likely an error in my test code (whatever it was).

Answer (score 1):

I'd write it

```
(dolist (item some-list)
  (let ((temp-var (some-function-of item)))
    ...))
```

Comment: ... which however loses the various value collection forms of cl-loop; In effect I would then wrap this into something like `(let (out-list) (BLA ... (push value out-list) ...) (reverse out-list))`. Not really an improvement to me I fear. Thanks for the suggestion though.